# Convert restricted RTF subset to plaintext with HTML formatting tags

Tags: wpf, regex, rtf

I'm looking to take the output of a WPF RichTextBox which is locked down to only allow certain formatting commands (Bold, Underlined and Italic), and parse it to be plaintext with HTML tags denoting the formatting. This is so that the formatting information can be picked up and parsed by an Oracle Publishing interface.

All other information such as font sizes, colors etc are not important, as they will be handled the Publishing template further down the line.

Ideally then we would have something like the following, stripping out all other rtf tags:

```
This is <b>some bold text, with <i>this bit</i> italic as well</b>
```

Is there a relatively easy way to do this? I've seen some Regex strings, but they always seem to let unwanted rtf material through. I don't want to use a commercial solution really, as its quite a small problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse HTML using regular expressions?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to parse RTF to produce plaintext with a pre-defined subset of HTML applied to it; so where there was a Bold command in RTF, this should be applied to the plaintext as HTML bold tags.

Comment: Well, nobody is going to be able to do that.  You have to provide expected input, expected output, and required language or languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse RTF and replace necessary control codes with HTML tags. Considering complexity of RTF, I don't think Regex will be enough.

- [Rich Text Format (RTF) Specification, version 1.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277(office.10).aspx). Syntax is relatively easy, you just need to process control codes like `\b` for bold etc., I think.
- [NRTFTree - A class library for RTF processing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx). Its SAX parser is probably what you need.

Comment: This is essentially what we're going to do I think. Using the solution provided here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx for full RTF to HTML conversion, then writing a much simpler parser to take the plain text with only the HTML tags we want out from that.